# proxy_pass return redirect in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am just a beginner who is currently studying nginx.
I have questions while using nginx's proxy_pass feature, so I have questions.

My website is test.com (just example).

```
http://test.com/aaa (This is example address)
```

-> aaa makes return to '/login/login.cgi'

And what I want is

```
http://test.com/aaa/login/login.cgi
```

But I just redirect to

```
http://test.com/login/login.cgi
```

And this is my nginx config (deleted unnecessary code)

```
server {
    location /aaa {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1/;
    }
}
```

How can I solve it?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1/` `<--` Anything you put on the end of here...

`location /aaa` `<--` Replaces whatever you put here.

So in your case `/aaa` gets replaced by `/`.

To keep the `/aaa` all you need to do is remove the slash from the end of your `proxy_pass` like this:

`proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1`